# unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING with quotes

Tags: php, php-parse-error

Can someone help me to find  what is wrong in the `$secret` line ?

`$secret` should give :

```
{"name":"JustAname","extra":"1","password":"ASD123","report":"http:\/\/website.com\/dev\/gamereport\/0001.php"}
```

here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
    $name = 'JustAname';
    $extra = '1';
    $password = 'ASD123';
    $reception = 'http:\/\/website.com\/dev\/gamereport.php';
    // Code de génération de la base64
    $secret = '{"name":"'.$name'","extra":"'.$extra'","password":"'.$password'","report":"'.$reception'"}';
    $encodedSecret = base64_encode($secret);


    $tournementLink = 'pvpnet://lol/customgame/joinorcreate/map1/pick6/team5/specALL/'.$encodedSecret;

    echo $tournementLink;
?>
```

I got: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in [...] on line 20

Comment: For some reason you put dots *before* all of your variables when building up the `$secret` string but not *after*.

Comment: `$secret = '{"name":"'. $Tournament . '","extra":"'. $extra . '"....` dots in between all the variables and single quoted strings...

Comment: This is a case where building the array data structure then using `json_encode()` on it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly concatenating strings, as @hobbs suggests. You're also using the undefined variable `$Tournament`, which I think should be `$name`. Try this:

```
$secret = '{"name":"' . $name . '","extra":"' . $extra . '","password":"' . $password . '","report":"' . $reception . '"}';
```

On a side note, a slightly nicer way to create JSON in PHP is to use an array and `json_encode()`:

```
$secret = json_encode(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'extra' => $extra,
        'password' => $password,
        'report' => $reception));
```

Comment: Maybe so based on the visible code, but that's not what caused this error.

Comment: Ah.. missed the obvious!

Comment: +1 for the json / array suggestion.  It's not *slightly* better... *way* better!

Comment: @RickyNotaro-Garcia Indeed - `json_encode()` takes care of all the escaping for you.